# spectrum of a sum of two compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis

If we have the compact operator A=B+C, which is the sum of two compact operator, is the spectrum of such operator A union of spectrum of operators B and C? 
We now that the spectrum of compact operator contains eigenvalues + 0.

Comment: In short: no. Do you know how to consider the spectrum of the sum of *matrices* (i.e. finite dimensional operators)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  Take $H=\ell^2$ with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, let $\{\beta_n\}$ and $\{\gamma_n\}$ be sequences convergent to $0$, and defined $B,C:H\to H$ by linear extension of 
$$B(e_n)=\beta_ne_n,$$ $$C(e_n)=\gamma_ne_n.$$
Then $B$ and $C$ are compact operators, with spectra $\sigma(B)=\{\beta_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$ and $\sigma(C)=\{\gamma_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$.  Now if $A=B+C$, then it is easy to see that $A$ is compact and that 
$$\sigma(A)=\{\beta_n+\gamma_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\},$$
which is in general not equal to $$\{\beta_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{\gamma_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}=\sigma(B)\cup\sigma(C).$$

Comment: thanks now its clear to me.